# why this jQuery does not work in Chrome?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a form. There is an input control I populate with the parameter `email`'s value from the url.

So, when the page is loaded, I automatically submit the form to mail chimp, like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit();
            if ($("#previousUrl").val().indexOf('?') != -1) {
                window.location.replace($("#previousUrl").val() + '&emailRegistered=true#newsletterAnchor');
            }
            else {
                window.location.replace($("#previousUrl").val() + '?emailRegistered=true#newsletterAnchor');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

and immediately after submit, I do a redirect to previous url.

Well, all this **works fine in Firefox** (a popup for confirmation is also opened after submitting the form and the main page is redirected back to the previous one.

I do not understand why this **does not work in Chrome**. I mean, *somehow the POST action is not finished, because no other popup is opened* (altought this page is redirecting back to the initial one).

Can you suggest me a way to do the redirect when FOR SURE the POST has been done? (in this way I think will work in Chrome too)...

**UPDATE**:

Form's target is "_blank" so the script from mail chimp (that's where I do POST) opens a confirmation popup window.

**UPDATE 2**:

Tried with ajax but for some reason it does not do anything...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').attr('action'),
                data: $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function () {
                    if ($("#previousUrl").val().indexOf('?') != -1) {
                        window.location.replace($("#previousUrl").val() + '&emailRegistered=true#newsletterAnchor');
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location.replace($("#previousUrl").val() + '?emailRegistered=true#newsletterAnchor');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: why your submit method is not last line in function body...

Comment: Because the flow is: Click on page 1 - go to page 2 (where this form is) - POST this form - Go back to page 1

Comment: so what I think that when it comes to submit it redirects, code below should not be executed. unles you have event attached to submit.

Comment: @Cristian: When you submit a form, you're making a request to go to a new page. `submit` doesn't submit a form then leave the current page standing.

Comment: Submit the form using ajax and then redirect.

Comment: @Arun: No AJAX required. Just submit to the form target, and have the form target perform the required redirection. Just like we've been doing for years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to submit a form and redirect to another page *at the same time*? You can't do that. You can only make one request at a time (without AJAX, that is).

Comment: Yeah,,,this is what I thought also...The questions is: If I do POST at first, how can I automatically redirect after POST is done?

Comment: @Cristian: Why not make your form target perform the redirection? After form submission, this first page is _gone_.

Comment: Good ideea...tried it (see my UPDATE please) but still have problems... The link is good for sure because using js redirect with that link works.

Comment: @Cristian: The `target` attribute is for the URL where you want to submit the form. Submit the form as usual, but make it so that the script that you submit the data to performs the desired redirection after handling the data.

Comment: Well, got it now... The problem is that I submit to mail chimp and I have no access to their code. If I specify _blank, their code opens the popup with confirmation. But, while opening this popup in another window, I still want the initial page with the form to redirect back to the previous page...

Comment: @Cristian: I'm sure that they will have some "redirect" parameter that you can piggyback on. Read the documentation.